# How can i copy data from NAND memory to sd card?

Tags: kernel, boot, linux-kernel, sd-card, flash-memory

So basically, i have two Gumstix Overo and both are booting from their NAND flash memory, both devices use full linux image's Kernel. They are supposed to boot the same thing but one of them says that it can't find a file and doesn't complete the boot. So i was wondering if i can copy the files from the nand memory of the one that is working to an empty sd card and then put the sd card on the other gumstix overo and boot from the sd card. I hope i could make myself understandable, i'm just beginning to handle a gumstix overo.

Comment: the question is less whether you can copy (yes), but whether you can boot a gumstix overo from SD card (don't know, might not be the case).

Comment: @MarcusMüller i think i can boot from SD card because if i erase the NAND memory and then reset, when i boot again i think he is going to boot from the sd card automtically, if the files are there

Comment: Maybe one of these helps: https://www.gumstix.com/community/support/faq/write-images-flash/ or https://www.gumstix.com/community/support/getting-started/get-image/ (Found with a quick search for "GUmstix Overo flashing")

Comment: @Bodo thanks, but i don't think so, because the image that i want is in the nand memory already, i don't have it anywhere else

Comment: @JoãoSousa I don't know if this image is available somewhere for download. (Maybe you can ask the manufacturer.) Even if you cannot use the linked instructions directly, they show at least some hints how writing (and reading) the flash memory might work. The first one mentions "*Linux mtd utilities*". Maybe you should read about this. Please show the exact error message in your question.

Comment: @JoãoSousa almost certainly, if you can boot it, you can also read it. It being in NAND memory should not be a problem.

Comment: @MarcusMüller but the problem is that i don't know how to copy it from the NAND memory to a sd card, don't even know what is the right command.

Comment: @Bodo The manufacturer would be the only source who would have the image. There isn't a specific error, i just wanted to know how to copy from nand to sd card because i don't know how.

Comment: ah, that's where the trouble lies.

Comment: @MarcusMüller i only have access to the uboot command line so even tho i know that the NAND memory is visible as /dev/mtd how don't know how to save it to an SD card through the uboot command line.

Comment: @JoãoSousa one of the devices actually boots, so yes, you can definitely use Linux to read that. Also, the website my answer links to tells you which uboot commands can be used to interact with the NAND memory.

Comment: @MarcusMüller thanks, i can only try what you sent tomorrow, then i will give an update if it worked

Comment: @MarcusMüller trying to follow the steps on the gumstix overo, that isn´t working right, from "Flashing with U-Boot" from the link you sent and now i can't access uboot on that overo, i can't reset know, what can i do? you can see the image in the link https://imgur.com/a/b8pUzzQ

Comment: the thing that says "cannot load kernel" (or whatever it says), that's uboot.

Comment: @MarcusMüller did you saw the image that i put in the comment? Becausa know i can't write anything on the command line, it just stays there, thats why i say i can't access uboot

Comment: @JoãoSousa Please [edit] your question and add all information, clarification or description and result of new attempts to your question instead of using comments for this purpose. The error "ECC failed" means that some data is corrupt in the Flash memory, and probably that the error cannot be fixed using ECC.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.gumstix.com/community/support/faq/write-images-flash/ points out that the NAND memory is visible as `/dev/mtd`; you should be able to interact with that as with any other block device. It also details how to write an image using uboot, so that you don't need to be able to boot linux to fix this.

So, you could save that NAND memory to an SD card, and tell uboot on the other overo to write it to mtd, done.